# What would be the best way to implement video ads for a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Currently making a video storage and streaming application. Right now I am trying to add ads to the application. What would be the best way to facilitate video ads for the app? I know that there is a google_mobile_ads package, but due to the guidelines of AdMob, I cannot show multiple video ads in a row. I would like to do something similar to YouTube where a series of 2 ads are shown to the user (in my case, 1 ad for every 30 minutes of content).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RobertWilliams Unfortunately no, I could not find anything. I ended up just adding an interstitial ad when my video player opens.

Comment: kk sharing my solution with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, when video starts get total video duration and determine how often you want to show ad. Then using a listener keep track of current position and show ad time to time. I have done something like this:

```
int adEvery = 0;
List<int> adIntervalSeconds = []; //timestamps at which ad will be shown
bool throttle = false;

videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
  int durationInSec = chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds;
  int positionInSec = chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds;

  //1500 sec = 25 minutes, isDurationLoaded bool used to make sure it run just once.
  if (durationInSec > 1500 && isDurationLoaded == false) {
    isDurationLoaded = true;

    //if duration > 25 mins then show ad every 20 mins approx.
    totalAds = (durationInSec ~/ 1200).toInt();
    adEvery = (durationInSec ~/ totalAds).toInt();

    //get timestamps in seconds list at which ad should be shown
    for (int i = 1; i < totalAds; i++) {
      adIntervalSeconds.add(adEvery * i);
    }     
    
  }

  if (videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying &&
      adIntervalSeconds.isNotEmpty &&
      adIntervalSeconds.contains(positionInSec) &&
      throttle == false) {
    throttle = true;
    
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      throttle = false;
    });

    adIntervalSeconds.remove(positionInSec);
    showInterstitial();
  }
}
```

This is what I came up with.